# how do I call sleep binary in ubuntu, via old javascript?

Tags: javascript, shell, ubuntu, lua, sleep

i want to get my program (mydicebot.AppImage) executes automatically, **¹3 times a day**, and **²after 7 consecutive winnings**, around every 8 hours.. and hopefully without wasting CPU resources and get everything slow down after the 8 hours wait.

i know that in Lua, i can make my program sleep with

```
function wait(time)
    local duration = os.time() + time
    while os.time() < duration do end
end
```

but it consumes CPU of my VM

so I tried

```
function wait(time)
    os.execute('sleep '.. tostring(time))
end
```

but this also returns error because my lua is in a pipe of javascript, so I tried

```
function sleep(s)
    local timer = io.popen("sleep " .. s)
    timer:close()
end
```

and io command also cannot be executed because it is already in a "pipe" of the main javascript program...

so i want to try migrating code to javascript... i love the idea of os.execute or io.popen, because it pauses the cpu, **not by cpu-consuming empty loop**...

*is there any working os.execute-like command in javascript, to call the original sleep binary in linux/ubuntu? if possible compatible with lowest version of javascript...*

because i tried

```
// Function implementation, parameter in seconds;
function wait(miao) {
    let shelljs = require('shelljs');
    shelljs.exec( "sleep" + " " + miao , { async : false } ) ;  
};

// Call the method; hibernate for 60 seconds, or 1 minute;
wait( 60 );
```

and it returns error of "let" needs esversion:6, and i tried many solution provided by many people with no luck..

```
function msleep(n) {
  Atomics.wait(new Int32Array(new SharedArrayBuffer(4)), 0, 0, n);
}
function sleep(n) {
  msleep(n*1000);
} 

sleep(30)
```

when called also returns sleep is undefined

```
var sleeper = require('sleep');
sleeper.sleep(n): sleep for n seconds
```

also return that sleeper is undefined

if i use `async function sleep() {` or `await sleep()` or `await new promise`, they are considered expression, even though the program expects assignment/function call...

also i cannot use `=>` or `let` because of esversion 6, while `setTimeout` is considered undefined

Comment: It would be better if you told us about the problem you're trying to solve, rather than your attempt to solve it.  See https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: This looks interesting: https://github.com/clementfarabet/async

Comment: hi Mr harvey, thanks for your trying to help, I have added my purpose.. and yes, it seems to be xy problems earlier, hahaha.. and ended up the link you provided being not helping in my goal achieving... so i edited my question details above..

Comment: `but this also returns error because my lua is in a pipe of javascript` - What is the error message?  Why nested `sleep` can not be piped?

Comment: Why not just run it when needed with cron?

Comment: firstly i don't know cron in js yet (lol), and i suppose that cron is asynchronously running, but i need the sleep after 5 consecutive winning (balance > balancestart)

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, it is just my assumption, because os.execute (with any content) returns " 'execute' returns nil value".... then io.popen returns error for the 'io'